# Difference between exists() and isDirectory() in android file class

Tags: android, file-io

I would like to check whether a folder in internal SD card is exist or not.
I have study android developer site.

> public boolean exists ()
>
> Added in API level 1
>   Returns a boolean indicating whether this file can be found on the underlying file system.
>
> public boolean isDirectory ()
>
> Added in API level 1
>   Indicates if this file represents a directory on the underlying file system.

It seems both of them can perform similar function.
What is the difference between them?
Which one of them will be better in my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a file that is present on file system,
exists() returns true but isDirectory returns false
directory is file that has zero or more files in it. File is not always directory.

Comment: @Armut Hello.Does it mean that both function will work but only the return value will be different?(For checking existing folder only)

Comment: yes. value will depend on file contents. Please accept the answer if your query is resolved.